# For which values of a do the following vectors form a linearly independent set in R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I've seen this same question, but asking for linearly dependent, not linearly independent.

$$ V_1= \left(a,\, \frac{-1}{2}, \,\frac{-1}{2}\right),\;\; V_2= \left(\frac{-1}{2},\, a, \,\frac{-1}{2}\right),\; \;V_3= \left(\frac{-1}{2}, \,\frac{-1}{2},\, a\right) $$

Here's what I got:

I used this equation:
$$k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3=0$$

$$(a)k_1+(\frac{-1}{2})k_2+(\frac{-1}{2})k_3=0$$

$$(\frac{-1}{2})k_1+(a)k_2+(\frac{-1}{2})k_3=0$$

$$(\frac{-1}{2})k_1+(\frac{-1}{2})k_2+(a)k_3=0$$

I substituted a few things a got to this:
$$a(2a-1)k_2=0$$

Which shows that $$a=0,1/2$$

The problem is that this doesn't show that the vectors are linearly independent because I haven't proven that $$k_1,k_2,k_3=0$$

Comment: Surround your latex with dollar-sign or double dollar-sign

Comment: Thanks @EnjoysMath, I couldn't understand why the latex wasn't working.

Comment: I assume by $\lambda$ (lambda) you mean $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to take the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}a&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&a&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&a\end{bmatrix}$

and then determine for which values of $a$ this is nonzero.

---

Alternatively, subtracting each pair of equations gives the equations

$(2a+1)k_1-(2a+1)k_3=0,\;\;(2a+1)k_2-(2a+1)k_3=0,\;\;(2a+1)k_1-(2a+1)k_2=0$.

If $a\ne-\frac{1}{2}$, then $k_1=k_2=k_3$ so substituting back in the first equation gives $(2a-2)k_1=0$.

If $a\ne1$, we get that $k_1=k_2=k_3=0$ and the vectors are linearly independent.

If $a=1$, then all 3 equations are satisfied when $k_1=k_2=k_3$, so the vectors are linearly dependent.

---

Equivalently, reducing the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\-\frac{1}{2}&a&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&a&0\end{bmatrix}$ for $a\ne-\frac{1}{2}\;\;$gives

$\begin{bmatrix}a&-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\-\frac{1}{2}&a&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&a&0\end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2a&1&0\\1&1&-2a&0\\-2a&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2a&1&0\\0&1+2a&-1-2a&0\\0&1+2a&1-4a^2&0\end{bmatrix}$

$\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2a&1&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&1&1-2a&0\end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2a&1&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&2-2a&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Now you can determine for which values of $a\ne-\frac{1}{2}$ this will have only the trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the triple product $\langle {\bf v}_1\times{\bf v}_2, {\bf v}_3\rangle.$ It is the oriented volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors. If the volume is zero, the vectors are coplanar and hence linearly dependent. If the volume is not zero, then the vectors are not coplanar, and hence linearly dependent. Analyze this quantity in terms of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of the matrix of the three vectors are easily computed to be $a-1$ and $a+1/2$. Now iff zero is an eigenvalue, the matrix is well known to be not invertible.